# Is there a way to edit My Domain using apex?

Tags: apex, url, mydomain, instance

I'm looking for a way to add or edit My Domain using Apex, **not from the UI**. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I am sure there is none but because couldn't find a documentation on this thus not providing this as an answer. I am though curious as why (and how) would you want to do it from Apex? My Domain requires to verify a sub domain before you can register it, which means there is a user interaction required for which you primarily need UI and in absence of it, I wonder how can you address that using Apex if say the one you are trying to register is already taken. What is the use case here and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) as far as I can tell. Why do you want to be able to do this? What else have you tried before determining that this path is the correct one? Why would you even want to automate this one-time-use setting?